# Plotting Multiple Line Graphs on the same Graph

Tags: r, plot

Can anybody tell me on how to use how to plot 2-line graphs on the same graph from  a table of four columns in a file. The second and the 3rd columns of the table are drawn as the line graphs and formed their values are used as the 'Y' component of the graph. Below is a fragment of the table:

```
1 0.870562 0.770139 0.636021
2 0.869924 0.802392 0.689587
3 0.911313 0.820322 0.762003
4 0.911265 0.840377 0.782875
5 0.913223 0.863843 0.797582
6 0.914712 0.879705 0.792843
7 0.917794 0.884944 0.784698
8 0.919051 0.888722 0.797559
9 0.919634 0.896603 0.780230
10 0.918743 0.887593 0.797525
11 0.919489 0.891662 0.801200
12 0.920888 0.904146 0.801903
13 0.925410 0.881502 0.799045
14 0.925046 0.894378 0.786870
15 0.936685 0.893323 0.800810
16 0.936955 0.885594 0.798582
17 0.935787 0.876707 0.759173
18 0.936909 0.880437 0.763847
19 0.936548 0.886330 0.794153
20 0.937337 0.888732 0.797475
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is you goal to plot multiple lines on the same figure, or to produce a figure that has multiple panels with one line on each?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but if you want to plot two lines, using the first column as X and the 2nd and 3rd columns as Ys, this could be what you are looking for...

Using ggplot2:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = your_dataframe, aes(x = column1, y = column2)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(aes(x = column1, y = column3))
```